# Is $l^2$ dense in $(l^{\infty}, \|\cdot\|_{\infty})$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Here I am using  $l^2$ to define the set of complex-sequences which are square summable and  $l^{\infty}$ to define the set of bounded complex sequences.

I think not. If we take $x(n) = 1 \;\; n\in \mathbb{N}$ ,which is bounded sequence. Then for any $y\in l^2$ must be a null sequence, so

$$\|x-y\|_{\infty} = \sup|1- y(n)| \geq 1$$

Comment: You are correct about it not being dense, but i don't know why you said any $y \in l^2$ must be a null sequence. It doesn't have to be null itself, rather the terms converge to $0$

Comment: @mathworker21 A null sequence is defined to be a sequence converging to zero.

Comment: Yup, that's correct. And the closure of $\ell^2$ in $\ell^{\infty}$ is $c_0$, the subspace of sequences converging to $0$.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I should have specified what I refer to as a null sequence!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is similar way, the function $\phi(x) = \limsup_n |x_n|$ is a 
continuous function on $l_\infty$ ( since $|\phi(x)-\phi(y)| \le \|x-y\|$) and $\phi((1,1,...)) = 1$, but
$\phi(x) = 0$ for all $x \in l_2$.

If $l_2$ was dense in $l_\infty$, then we would have $x_n \in l_2$ such that $x_n \to (1,1,...)$ (in $l_\infty$) and then $\phi(x_n) \to 1$
which would be a contradiction.